# Azure Cognitive Search multiple fields with different text

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-search

Microsoft.Azure.Search is deprecated and upgrading to Azure.Search.Documents. In Azure Cognitive search, how should we pass multiple fields with different search text to the query.

For example, searching for an item with red color, triangle shape and steel metal:  color=red & shape=triangle & metal=steel. I am able to search a simple text in multiple fields. How to achieve multiple field search.

```
public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> FindEntities(string searchText, List<string> searchFields = null, List<string> orderFields = null)
{
    try
    {
        var indexClient = CreateSearchIndexClient();
                 
        SearchOptions searchOptions = GetSearchOptions(searchFields, orderFields);
    
        var documentSearchResult = await indexClient.SearchAsync<TResult>(Uri.EscapeDataString(searchText), searchOptions);

        IEnumerable<TResult> searchResults = documentSearchResult.Value.GetResults().Select(x => x.Document);
                     
        return ConstructEntity(searchResults);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error(ex.ToString(), ex);
        throw;
    }
}

private static SearchOptions GetSearchOptions(List<string> searchFields = null, List<string> orderFields = null)
{            
    SearchOptions searchOptions = new SearchOptions() {
         
        SearchMode = SearchMode.All,                 // Set the search mode to All            
        IncludeTotalCount = true,                   // Include total result count                      
    };

    if((searchFields != null && searchFields.Any()) && (orderFields == null || !orderFields.Any()))
    {
        var fields = string.Join(",",searchFields);
        SearchOptions fieldOptions = new SearchOptions
        {
            Filter = searchOptions.Filter,
            Size = searchOptions.Size,
            SearchFields = { fields }
        };                
        return fieldOptions;
    }

    if ((orderFields != null && orderFields.Any()) && (searchFields == null && !searchFields.Any()))
    {
        var order = string.Join(",", orderFields.Select(field => field + " asc"));
        SearchOptions sortedOptions = new SearchOptions
        {
            Filter = searchOptions.Filter,
            Size = searchOptions.Size,
            OrderBy = { order }
        };
        return sortedOptions;
    }

    if ((orderFields != null && orderFields.Any()) && (searchFields != null && searchFields.Any()))
    {
        var order = string.Join(",", orderFields.Select(field => field + " asc"));
        var fields = string.Join(",", searchFields);
        SearchOptions fieldsortedOptions = new SearchOptions
        {
            Filter = searchOptions.Filter,
            Size = searchOptions.Size,
            OrderBy = { order },
            SearchFields = { fields }
        };
        
        return fieldsortedOptions;
    }
    return searchOptions;
}
```

Tried single text search in multiple fields. Working as expected. Need to search multiple texts in multiple fields.

This is done in Microsoft.Azure.Search, using a space separated text in the searchText field.
ex: "red triangle steel" as search text and search parameters "color,shape,metal".

However, the same syntax with space separated text is not working for cognitive search.

Answer (score 0):

Based on provide information, I have created an index with uploaded below data:

```json
new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "id", "1" },
    { "color", "red" },
    { "shape", "circle" },
    { "material", "steel" }
},
new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "id", "2" },
    { "color", "blue" },
    { "shape", "triangle" },
    { "material", "plastic" }
},
new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "id", "3" },
    { "color", "blue" },
    { "shape", "red" },
    { "material", "plastic" }
}
```

To get search result from multiple fields with different text, you can use `filter` in `Search Option.`

Below is sample `code snippet` and `query` that can be used for the task:

> searchQuery/Filter = "color eq 'red' or shape eq 'triangle' or material eq 'steel'"

```cs
SearchClient searchClient = new SearchClient(new Uri($"https://{serviceName}.search.windows.net/"), indexName, new AzureKeyCredential(adminKey));
            
// Test Azure Cognitive Search with multiple fields
string searchQuery = "color eq 'red' or shape eq 'triangle' or material eq 'steel'";
SearchOptions searchOptions = new SearchOptions
{
    Filter = searchQuery
};
SearchResults<Dictionary<string, object>> searchResults = await searchClient.SearchAsync<Dictionary<string, object>>("*", searchOptions);

foreach (var result in searchResults.GetResults())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Document: {result.Document}");
    foreach (var kvp in result.Document)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Key: {kvp.Key}, Value: {kvp.Value}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

With above code snippet and query filter, I was able to get required results.
[image]

For more examples, check this [documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents#examples)